# Run react native for android from shared JS folder

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to keep my react-native code in a separate folder, and be used by both android and iOS projects?

I currently have an application that exists for iOS and Android. I have a need to use react-native for the application, and am having some issues. I have a 3 folder structure to accomplish this: android, ios, and js. Currently, I have the iOS project working properly, but the android project is where the trouble comes in. When I run the android application on an emulator or device, I get the error `Could not connect to development server`.

My setup for my Activity is such:

```
reactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
    .setApplication(getApplication())
    .setJSMainModuleName("index.android")
    .addPackage(new MainReactPackage())
    .setUseDeveloperSupport(true)
    .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
    .build();
reactRootView.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "SimpleApp", null);
setContentView(reactRootView);
```

When I run this, the error window indicates it cannot connect to the server, which is a completely different IP address than my localhost (on computer).

I have tried running on device, and doing the `adb reverse` command, but the result is the same.

I have also tried adding:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        preferences.edit().putString("debug_http_host", "localhost:8081").apply();
```

But this still results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Using native code along with JS is a little cumbersome(i dont know if it will work or not) you can create your application for both ios and android by just writing the code once in js using react native.And as for your *Could not connect to development server* you have to go to the root folder of your app and run **react-native start** that will run the packager. read through the following link for a tutorial on react-native [React-native](https://devdactic.com/react-native-for-beginners/)

Comment: I currently am running react-native from the JS folder, and I can open a browser in the emulator and point to localhost:8081/index.android.js and see the file. The application, however, cannot. I think it is more related to my `ReactInstanceManager` setup.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to my answer provided in following thread.

[Packager not started after running "react-native run-android"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141646/packager-not-started-after-running-react-native-run-android)

Hope it will help you.